# Multiple files upload using swagger operation

Tags: rest, python-2.7, swagger, swagger-ui, multiple-file-upload

I am currently doing multiple files upload using swagger operation. Following are the codes that I am working with:

```
class uploadImage(Resource):

  @swagger.operation(

        notes='Upload an image file',

        parameters=[
          {
            "name": "file[]",
            "description": "Upload an image file. File size limit is 3MB. Only '.jpg' is allowed ",
            "required": True,
            "allowMultiple": True,
            "dataType": 'file',
            "paramType": "form"
          }
])

def post(self):
    files=request.files.getlist['file[]']
    filenames = []
    for file in files:
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        filenames.append(filename)
        print "Files are uploaded successfully"
```

Although I inserted **"allowMultiple":True** in the code, but it did not show in the swagger UI. Once the server is up, I try to view the html source code, **"multiple" does not display in the form.**

Following is the source code for swagger ui when the server is up:

```
<input class="parameter" type="file" name="file[]">
```

The word "multiple" is missing from the .

If I edit the source code and add in the word "multiple" as below, I manage to select multiple files.

```
<input class="parameter" type="file" name="file[]" multiple>
```

It seems like **"allowMultiple":True** does not work for me in this case.

Any idea or suggestion for me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

this already support by swagger in OpenAPI 3.0. See https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/file-upload/

example:

```
  /schema:
    get:
      tags:
        - Schema
      description: download schema file
      responses:
        "200":
          description: success
          content:
            multipart/form-data:
              schema:
                 type: object
                 properties:
                   filename:
                     type: array
                     items:
                       type: string
                       format: binary
        "400":
          $ref: "#/components/responses/failed"
        "404":
          $ref: "#/components/responses/notExist"
```

[effect picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsOBC.png)

Comment: This does not work with streaming file upload

Answer (score 3):

That's just not supported by Swagger. See https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/issues/254.

Comment: Thanks @Ron. I have changed the method. Only one file is allowed.

Comment: Update: OpenAPI 3.0 supports describing multipart requests containing an array of files. This can be tested in Swagger UI 3.26.0+.